# Register/login/ form- activation link

Tags: php

So i have been taking a course in webdevelopment and while building a website i started having issues when creating register/login page.  When i leave values blank in the register form and hit "submit".  I get the errors missing "username, email, password etc."  however, it stores the empty values in my database.  Another issue, is when i type in the password, it will prompt me how long the password should be even after i put the correct value for password, then it doesn't prompt me to confirm the new passwords so they match.  Even putting any password it will accept it and i will get both the error that the password should be at least 8 char long, 1 capital letter etc. but i will also get a "success" message saying that i have received an "activation link" in email.  When i click the activation link, it say "activated" and says so in database, but when i try to login with the info, it says "wrong username or password".

I am very new to all this but i just could not find the solution to this.

This is my code in register

```
<!--Start a session-->
<?php
session_start();


//here we are connecting to db by linking the file to connection.php
include('connections.php');

//Check user inputs
//    Define error message

$missingUsername = '<p><strong>Please enter the username!</strong></p>';
$missingEmail = '<p><strong>Please enter your email!</strong></p>';
$invalidEmail = '<p><strong>Please enter a valid email</strong></p>';
$missingPassword = '<p><strong>Please enter a password!</strong></p>';
$invalidPassword = '<p><strong>Your password should be at least 8 characters long and include one capital letter and one number!</strong></p>';
$differentPassword2 = '<p><strong>The passwords don\'t match!</strong></p>';
$missingPassword2 = '<p><strong>Please enter password again</strong></p>';


//Get username, email, password, passwowrd2

//GET USERNAME
if(empty($_POST["username"])){

    $errors .= $missingUsername;

}else{
    $username = filter_var($_POST["username"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}

//GET EMAIL
if(empty($_POST["email"])){

$errors .= $missingEmail;

}else{
    $email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

//    VALIDATING EMAIL if email invalid
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){

    $errors .= $invalidEmail;
}    

}
//GET PASSWORDs

if(empty($_POST["password"])){

    $errors .= $missingPassword;

}elseif(!(strlen($_POST["password"])>8 
         and preg_match('/[A-Z]/',$_POST["password"])
         and preg_match('/[0-9]/',$_POST["password"]))){

    $errors .= $invalidPassword;

}else{
        $password = filter_var($_POST["password"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//IF SECOND PASSWORD MISSING 

    if(empty($_POST["password2"])){

    $errors .= $missingPassword2;
}else{
    $password2 = filter_var($_POST["password2"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        if($password !== $password2){

        $errors .= $differentPassword;
    }
  }
}

//IF THERE ARE ANY ERRROR    PRINT ERRORS

if($errors){
    $resultMessage = '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $errors . '</div>';
    echo $resultMessage;
}

//IF THERE ARE NO ERRORS

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$username);

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$email);

$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$password);

//hashing password

//$_Password = md5($_Password);
$password = hash('sha256',$password);
//128 bits -> 32 characters
//256 bits ->64 characters

//IF *USERNAME* EXISTS IN THE USERS TABLE PRINT ERROR


$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if(!$result){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Error running the query!</div>';

    //echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">'. mysqli_error($link).'</div>';

    exit;
}
$results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($results){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">That username is already registered. Do you want to log in?</div>';

    exit;
}

//IF THE *EMAIL* exists in the users table print error    

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if(!$result){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Error running the query!</div>';

    exit;
}
$results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($results){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">That email is already registered. Do you want to login?</div>';

    exit;
}

//CREATE A UNIQUE ACTIVATION CODE

$activationKey =
 bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
//     bytes:unit of data = 8 bits
//     bit: 0 or 1
//     16 bytes = 16 * 8= 128 bits
//     (2*2*2*2)*2*2*2*2...*2
//     16*16*...*16
//     32 characters

//INSERT USER DETAILS AND ACTIVATION CODE IN THE USERS TABLE

 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, activation) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password', '$activationKey')";   

 $result =  mysqli_query($link, $sql);

 if(!$result){
     echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">There was an error inserting users detail in the database!</div>';

     exit;
 }   

 //SEND THE USER AN EMAIL WITH A LINK TO ACTIVATE.PHP WITH THEIR EMAIL AND ACTIVATION CODE
$message = "Please click on this link to activate your account:\n\n";
$message .= "" . urlencode($email) . "&key=$activationKey";

if(mail($email, 'Confirm your registration', $message, 'From:'.'muharem22@gmail.com')){

    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Thank you for registering! A confirmation email has been sent to $email. Please click on the activation link to activate your account!</div>";
}

?>
```

[Here is a screen shot of my register form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2sNg.png)

Thank you for any suggestions/advice

Comment: why is this tagged as javascript/jquery/ajax/twitter-bootstrap?

Comment: _Suggestion:_ Use PHP's `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` instead of `hash()`. They come with proper hashing techniques like unique salts etc. Using `sha256` straight off still makes the passwords open to rainbow table attacks if someone would get a hold of the hashed passwords.

Comment: Instead of `if (!(strlen(($_POST["password"])>8 AND ...`, do `if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 8 AND ...`. Currently, you're actually passing the complete string `$_POST["password"])>8 and preg_match('/[A-Z]/',$_POST["password"])` as the argument to `strlen()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with empty entry in the database is because the code don't stop when found any error.

you have to add exit when found any error.

```
if($errors)
{
    $resultMessage = '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $errors . '</div>';
    echo $resultMessage;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you,  i must have looked over this code like 100x and didn't see that part :).